# How do you change font in bigcommerce cornerstone theme?

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I added new fonts on shogun builder, but how do I reference that to my .ttf file?

I also tried creating a fontface but also not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the font-face definition to the head in /templates/layout/base.html as

```
             font-family: "Kelvingrove-Regular";
             font-style: normal;
             font-weight: 400;
             src: url("{{cdn 'webdav:385BF6_4_0.woff'}}") format("woff"),
             url("{{cdn 'webdav:385BF6_4_0.woff2'}}") format("woff2"),
             url("{{cdn 'webdav:385BF6_4_0.ttf'}}") format("truetype"),
             url("{{cdn 'webdav:385BF6_4_0.eot'}}");
         }
```

Then drop the font file onto your BigCommerce server via webdav (cyberduck) in the "content" folder.